# How to use tagDEC in Delphi

Tags: .net, delphi, com, com-interop, delphi-2007

I have imported a .Net Class Library made available through COM Interop into Delphi 2007, and a Decimal data type was made available as a tagDEC packed record. How do I fill use this record type so I can use the Class Library? 
Tks

**Edit**

Below is my C# code that is exposed as a ActiveX through COM Interop:

```
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
  [ProgId("ClassLibrary.Class1")]
  public class Class1
  {
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public string Method1(DateTime pDateTime, int pID, decimal pQty)
    {
...........    
    }
  }
```

I register the library with regasm on the PC with Delphi, with the command below:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe .\ClassLibrary.dll /tlb:ClassLibrary.tlb
```

In Delphi 2007, through the Import Component, I import the Type Library, and it get's converted into the following method at the proxy class:

```
function Method1(pDateTime: TDateTime; pID: Integer; pQty: TDecimal): WideString;
```

The `TDecimal` is actually a `packed record` of type `tagDEC`, found in the `ActiveX` unit. Below is it's syntax:

```
{ from WTYPES.H }
  PDecimal = ^TDecimal;
  {$EXTERNALSYM tagDEC}
  tagDEC = packed record
    wReserved: Word;
    case Integer of
      0: (scale, sign: Byte; Hi32: Longint;
      case Integer of
        0: (Lo32, Mid32: Longint);
        1: (Lo64: LONGLONG));
      1: (signscale: Word);
  end;
  TDecimal = tagDEC;
  {$EXTERNALSYM DECIMAL}
  DECIMAL = TDecimal;
```

My question is how to I fill this in, so I can pass the decimal value into the .Net Class Library method? Is there any helper function? I didn't find any.
Tks again!

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to answer this question at the moment. Could you please supply some more details.

Comment: What's the structure of tagDEC packed record? where it comes from... RTL?

Comment: Just edited the post with all of the details, C# and Delphi. Tks so much

Answer (score 1):

By coincidence, I had  the opposite problem this week: I'm consuming a C# library through COM in Delphi, where some of the C# methods return a `decimal` (a `TDecimal` or `tagDEC` in Delphi), and was also wondering what to do with it.

After searching through the ActiveX, ComObj and OleServer units I found this function:

```
VarR8FromDec(PDecimal, out double);
```

Which did the trick. I have Delphi, nor the aforementioned sources handy here, but chances are that in you'll find a method in those units that will do the reverse.

Not a clear cut answer, but maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple try? I'm not a .NETty, so I can' test, but

e.g. Set scale to 10000, hi32 to 5432 and sign to 0.  So a luckily attempt to pass +5432/10000= 0.5432, assuming sign is TRUE for negative and 0 for positive (it may be the other way around)

I am a bit concerned with your header though. The "p" Hungarian prefix seems to indicate pointer values.

```
  var x : TAGDEC;
  begin
    x.scale:=10000;
    x.hi32:=5432;
    x.sign:=0;
    comobject.method1(theDateTime,thePID,x);
  end;
```

Comment: the scale property is a Byte, so I can't assign it a value this high.

Comment: @Pascal Scale is in the range 0-28 and is a power of 10 exponent - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc208367.aspx Trial and error is fraught with dangers!!

Answer (score 0):

You could regard Decimal as an opaque type if you wish. To do so you would export from your C# code the helpers you need to synthesise Decimal values and then call that code from Delphi. My guess is that you would want a Double -> Decimal helper and perhaps vice versa.

Alternatively you could modify the C#/COM interface to use doubles and convert to Decimal on the C# side of the fence.

Comment: I actually did that to get on with the project, and deliver it. I posted the question to see if there was anyone that has actually used this tagDEC record type, so I could do it properly. After all, in the future, I might not be able to change the data type of the variable so I could use it in Delphi. Tks

Comment: @Pascal I think if you can make use of .net's knowledge of Decimal that is always the way to go. The best documentation I have found on the Decimal type is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc208367.aspx

Comment: Tks for the link. That's a lot better than this one (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221061.aspx) I had. I'll try it out